# install opencv python mac osx 10.11?

Tags: python, macos, opencv, osx-elcapitan

I'm trying to install opencv so I can use it in a python program. My computer is a little old and I can't update osx past 10.11. Is it still possible to install opencv? I don't need it to be opencv4 if that's an issue.

I've tried using pip, pip3, and homebrew. They all download it and then it won't actually import in python correctly. Everything eventually says that it needs to be osx 10.12.

Here's the exact error I'm getting:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/libavutil.56.22.100.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/libavutil.56.22.100.dylib
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you have Anaconda. Have you tried installing via conda install?

Comment: `_clock_gettime` is available only in MacOS 10.12 and later, so you won't be able to install recent versions of `opencv` - install the pre-4 version: `pip install "opencv-python<4"` or `conda install "opencv<4"` etc.

Comment: Yeah I've tried with conda install. Doesn't seem to work. Frankly, I don't actually use anaconda for anything; I'm new to all of this and just installed it because someone I knew told me it would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try conda install :

```
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo opencv3
```

OR

```
conda install -c menpo opencv
```

Then import

```
import cv2
```

There seems to be a problem with the brew installation according to https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/3024 but you can try the below too

---------- OR ----------

First, create a `venv` (Virtual Enviorment)

```
python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment
```

Then using brew :

```
brew uninstall opencv
brew install opencv3
```

**OR**

Then using pip :

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

Finally, import using :

```
import cv2
```

This should work but in the case doesn't it might mean that you've installed anaconda with python in that case try:

```
conda install -c menpo opencv
```

Finally, import using :

```
import cv2
```

Comment: The second one seemed to work--I had to make an environment with python 2 instead of 3 for whatever reason. Thanks so much!